# Python: method chaining not working as expected - creating and sorting a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a list and sort it.
If I am splitting the steps in separate statements, it works like I expect:

```
mylist = [4, 1, 2, 6, 0, 9]
mylist.sort()
```

gives me the expected result:

```
[0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 9]
```

while

```
mylist = [4, 1, 2, 6, 0, 9].sort()
```

results in

```
None
```

I don't understand why.
I would expect, that in the second example, the list would be sorted and assigned to `mylist`

Comment: `list.sort()` returns `None`. What's there to explain?

Comment: Python actually does not do much *chaining*. In fact chaining can frequently lead to unwanted side-effects.